# Set API Key to be required for AWS ApiGateway endpoint (Swagger import)

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I try to define my AWS Api Gateway infrastructure using Swagger/OpenAPI. Everything is working so far, however I have problems enabling the need for an API-Key for my endpoints.

My Swagger file looks like this (shortened):

```
---
swagger: 2.0
basePath: /dev
info:
  title: My API
  description: Proof of concept
schemes:
  - https
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: X-Api-Key
    in: header

paths:
  /example-path:
    options:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: mock
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: |
            {
              "statusCode" : 200
            }
        responses:
          "default":
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
            responseTemplates:
              application/json: |
                {}
    responses:
      200:
        description: Default response for CORS method
        headers:
          Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
            type: "string"
          Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
            type: "string"
          Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
            type: "string"          

    get:
      security:
        - api_key: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:

        # Further definition of the endpoint, calling Lambda etc...
```

Linked inside a CloudFormation template the Swagger file is processed successfully. But when I open the endpoint in the AWS Web Console, the flag for **API Key Required** is still *false*.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the solution: the API key has to be named `x-api-key` (all lowercase).

It seems like only this way the setting is recognized during import.

Comment: Source for the answer is the sentence that reads "The client can now call the API methods while supplying the x-api-key header with the chosen API key as the header value." seen in the aws docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html

Comment: Can we get a fully functioning example. geez

Answer (score 7):

To enable required API Key you need to add this `"x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source" : "HEADER"` in security scheme block.

See an example:

```
    "components" : {
        "securitySchemes" : {
          "api-key" : {
            "type" : "apiKey",
            "name" : "x-api-key",
            "in" : "header",
            "x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source" : "HEADER"
          }
        }
      }
```

It's an example using proxy requests.
Your JSON should be like this:
openapi3

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.3",
    "info": {
      "title": "User Portal",
      "description": "API focused in User Portal.",
      "version": "v1"
    },
    "paths": {
      "users/{proxy+}": {
        "options": {
            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
              "httpMethod": "OPTIONS",
              "payloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
              "type": "MOCK"
            }
          },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
          "produces":[ "application/json"],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "proxy",
              "in": "path",
              "required": "true",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ],
          "responses": {},
          "security": [
            {
              "api-key": []
          }
        ],
          "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
            "uri":"https://test.com.br/users/{proxy}",
            "httpMethod":"ANY",
            "type": "HTTP_PROXY"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "components" : {
        "securitySchemes" : {
          "api-key" : {
            "type" : "apiKey",
            "name" : "x-api-key",
            "in" : "header",
            "x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source" : "HEADER"
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

In openapi2 you can add this in your yml.

```
swagger: 2.0
basePath: /dev
info:
  title: My API
  description: Proof of concept
schemes:
  - https
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: X-Api-Key
    in: header
    x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER
```

If you have troubles using api integration with openapi you can see this article: [Working with API Gateway extensions to OpenAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html)

Comment: Components section is for Open API 3.0 and the question is specific to Open API 2.0

Comment: Tetenda Zifudzi I added an example to Open API 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sam templates for my deployment and I do NOT specify the ApiKeyRequired for either the API or the Functions (since my understanding is that the sam template will not override the api key configuration defined in an external definition body) and am trying to define that in the body defintion contained in in the open api spec I create. The only way I have been able to get the api_key to get applied selectively to each of my methods/endpoints is to use an Open API **2** instead of Open Api **3**.

In my Open Api 2 version, on endpoints that need the api key, I have this on the endpoints that need the key:

```
security:
      - api_key: []
:
:
```

and then this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "x-api-key"
    in: "header"
```

This works and the sam deploy appropriately applies the api_key to the endpoints that I need it on.

If I use Open Api 3, however, the api key does **NOT** get applied:

```
security:
      - api_key: []
:
:
components:
securitySchemes:
    api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "x-api-key"
    in: "header"
    "x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source" : "HEADER"
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get the api_key to be applied using an Open Api 3 doc?  All my other APIs use the 3 spec and not really wanting to use 2 just because I can't get a 3 to deploy correctly.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34603928)