# Importing Open API 3.0 to the Amazon API Gateway - mandatory API Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, openapi, aws-api-gateway

I worked through most(all?) of the docs of OpenAPI 3.0 extensions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html) but I could not find an example how to enforce using api keys on method. Basically I'd like to mirror [what is shown here (in section "Require API key on a method")](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html#api-gateway-usage-plan-configure-apikey-on-method) but using OpenAPI `.yaml` file(when importing it to the API Gateway).

Any ideas?

[This example of Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html#openapi-3.0) has a brief `type: "apiKey"` somewhere but I am not sure if this is linked to my issue.

Comment: I think that API key is configured as an OpenAPI security scheme and not as AWS extensions. See if this helps: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/

Comment: This question seems to be already asked in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553093/set-api-key-to-be-required-for-aws-apigateway-endpoint-swagger-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen), the API key is configured as an OpenAPI security scheme and not as AWS extensions.

For Open API 3.0, try the following configuration at root level.

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:        # arbitrary name for the security scheme
      type: apiKey
      in: header       
      name: x-api-key  # name of the header, query parameter or cookie
```

Then apply the following configuration at root of path method level

```
security:
  - ApiKeyAuth: []
```

See more information here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/

Comment: The answer is incomplete for AWS API Gateway. 
Please see the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553093/set-api-key-to-be-required-for-aws-apigateway-endpoint-swagger-import

Comment: The answer was intentionally kept as a snippet for brevity. Feel free to refer to @EkkardS's linked question for the full configuration.